# SQL - Grouping with order condition

Tags: sql, group-by

I am new with SQL and have some data in table and want to make grouping based on column `CLASS` and `STATUS` with condition based on the value in both column. It will group based on the highest order

The Table shown below

**Scenario 1**

**Table Source** :

| ID | Class | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Platinum | ACTIVE |
| 001 | Gold | ACTIVE |
| 001 | Silver | ACTIVE |
| 001 | Regular | ACTIVE |

**Output after Grouping**:

| ID | Class | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Platinum | ACTIVE |

**Scenario 2**

**Table Source** :

| ID | Class | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Gold | ACTIVE |
| 001 | Silver | INACTIVE |
| 001 | Regular | INACTIVE |

**Output after Grouping**:

| ID | Class | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Gold | ACTIVE |

So basically the grouping will be determined by the value of `CLASS` and `Status`

For `CLASS` the order of grouping is
**Platinum > Gold > Silver > Regular**

For `Status` the order of grouping is
**ACTIVE > INACTIVE**

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sql case` statement to define the order for each `class` and `subject`. then sort the resulting table as subquery.

```
select t1.ID, t1.class, t1.Status from (
    select ID, Class, Status (case when 'Platinum' then 1 when 'Gold' then 2 when 'Silver' then 3 else 4 end) as sort_order1,
        (case when 'active' then 1 else 2 end) as sort_order2
    from table1)
order by t1.sort_order1, t1.sort_order2
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your explanation.
I tried your suggestion and add with some CTE and it works!
Thanks for the insight!